# Unescaped control character around character 1461

Tags: ios, objective-c, promisekit

I'm hitting web service base below params.

```
posting params: {
  "UserToken" : "TTTqQECAwQAAQAAAAACvAAAAAsAARTaGRysdfsdT1o34lKDwzWjKhniDnKozOlMmb1gAAAGkABVNkYXRsdfsdfQAAsdfsdf+FQi6FVKDdE4sdf4HdfzcVDc53PEzc7FycZBImxAw0AXMjLTsrDSM+VkOlNKYnXx2\/5OMXIuW2Go9VZaM\/EC+pIM6w==",
  "MobileCode" : "2.0"
}
```

But I'm unable to hit the services. I'm getting below error.

```
Error : 
NSDebugDescription: Unescaped control character around character 1461.
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: add the code of  create params dictionary

Comment: I think your string is not escaped properly. `..\/5OMXIuW2Go9VZaM\/EC...`

Comment: yes. so i need to remove the \ / symbols ?

Comment: You need to *escape* the backslashes, so `\/` -> `\\/`.